# how to update FrontEnd in real time when the database get update from other apps?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, azure

first of all many thx in advance.

I have deployed my django(1.11) project to azure, it works together with the postgresql db. Now for the frontEnd I would like to build up a live chart/figure, which means that every time when the postgresql db receive any update (from the *function app* on azure, not the django self), my chart/figure should be automatically refreshed.

I have tried Signal, but it only react to the update which is made by django self. Then I try channels + redis, followed up the example(chat), but still not sure how to make it.

my question is: which package/ components/ Tech should I use in this case? can you guys give me some example or a link to the certain tutorial?

Look forward to the fancy idea from u guys.

Comment: Generally speaking, pushing updates to a frontend directly is not very helpful. What if multiple updates come in with very low delay between them (e.g <100 ms)? Even if the changed numbers would make it to the frontend, who is going to react on them? One option is to request data by the frontend using a channel, which then executes a `SELECT` at the server, in desired intervals.

Comment: nice idea, thanks for the positive reply. I will have a try on it.